# In many models, many objects have vanished and just appear as dots. Why?

Tags: objects, linux

My GPU is an Intel HD Graphics 530 - driver: i915 v: kernel.
on Linux Cinnamon.

A bunch of my models suddenly look very different in Blender. Some objects look unchanged, but most of the objects in any given model only show up as an orange dot at the object's center. In these cases the object itself is invisible, and yes they are all marked as visible and renderable.

Some models have dozens of objects and almost all of them have this useless behaviour. Closing and reopening Blender did not help. All the objects are meshes of simple shapes, combined with boolean operators (just about always Difference.)

I assumed I'd somehow corrupted Blender, so I deleted it and installed 2.91 (Linux). I opened models and the problem still exists. I can only assume there's some strange setting that's sticky across installations and models, but I'm still moderately new at Blender so I'm only guessing.

I have a lot of complicated models at this point that I do not want to lose. I don't want to try editing them (not that I could see what I was doing) for feat of doing more damage. Can someone walk me through fixing this?

This should look something like a vacuum tube (and used to):[image: screenshot]

Blend file: [Something like a vaccuum tube](http://ikrast.herbison.com:82/gunEmitterWhite.blend)

Comment: Can you please add images in the question to make it clearer

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel

Comment: Oh, nevermind then. I'll try to get the question reopened. Never seen that one before...

Comment: try opening the files with a previous version of blender. Also consider sharing the file so that others can take a look at it.

Comment: Added URL for the blend file for the model shown above. It's very possible I clobbered some setting in Blender, but I don't see it. I tried this in the original 2.83.5 and in 2.91.0; no difference.

Comment: Opens fine on my end with 2.91.0 If you create a new file and append every object, is it still buggy ? Also side node, with version 2.91 you can add whole collections as booleans, so you just need the one modifier and group all your cutter objects into one collection. One object can be part of multiple collections too

Answer (score 1):

I rebooted the system, and perhaps related, switched from Cinnamon's software rendering to hardware rendering in the reboot (but it's been set to software forever). The problem went away.